# Spinning Top revolutions calculations

Tags: speed

Is it possible to calculate spinning [top](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top) revolutions per minute?

Will the Spinning top material make a difference to the speed revolutions per minute?

Example : Wood, Plastic, Steel etc

Comment: you should clarify how the top is put i n motion, in most cases this gives you the initial revolutions per second or minute, the material plays only a role how long the initial speed takes to go to zero.

Comment: So a Material change for the Top will increase or decrease the Spinning top speed? The Top is spinned by the Rope Thread.

Comment: No the speed on the beginning can be calculated from the speed of the rope. With the same geometry of the top it is independent of the material, but the heavier top will turn longer bevor it stops.